# Grey splash screen due to no repainting

Tags: java, image, swing, splash-screen, graphics2d

I'm making a splash screen for my application. It's just static BufferedImage drawn by Graphics2D, inside JFrame with no decorations. My problem is: the window sometimes isn't drawn properly, it means it doesn't always contain my image, it's sometimes just grey. I tried already creating splash screen in second thread, but it didn't help. I could call `splashScreen.repaint()` every line, but it's nonsense... Here's my code:

```
package SeriousSteve.MapEditor;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * Simple splash screen, contains only the image.
 * 
 * @author m4tx3
 */
public class SplashScreen extends JFrame {

    private BufferedImage image;

    /**
     * Constructor. Creates a window with splash screen, loads an image at the
     * URL specified in imageURL, and finally displays this image.
     * 
     * @param imageURL  URL to the image that you want to put on the splash
     *                  screen.
     */
    public SplashScreen() {
        super("Splash screen");
    }

    public void createSplashScreen(final URL imageURL) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SplashScreen.class.getName()).
                    log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        setUndecorated(true);
        setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        createGraphics();

        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a graphics context and draws a splash screen.
     */
    private void createGraphics() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    /**
     * Closes the splash screen and frees the memory taken by the image.
     * 
     * Call this function when the loading is complete.
     */
    public void close() {
        setVisible(false);
        image = null;
        dispose();
    }
}
```

And:

```
    SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
    splashScreen.createSplashScreen(getClass().getResource(
            "Img/splash.png"));
```

Btw., - I'm creating my own splash screen class, because I've got 2 apps (the game and map editor for it) in 1 jar... I want to show splash screen only in map editor, so I can't modify manifest file.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `JLabel` instead. Painting on the frame directly is a bad idea.

See this, it works everytime:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Simple splash screen, contains only the image.
 * 
 * @author m4tx3
 */
public class SplashScreen extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Constructor. Creates a window with splash screen, loads an image at the URL specified in imageURL, and finally displays this image.
     * 
     * @param imageURL
     *            URL to the image that you want to put on the splash screen.
     */
    public SplashScreen() {
        super("Splash screen");
    }

    public void createSplashScreen(final URL imageURL) {

        JLabel splashLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageURL));
        add(splashLabel);
            setSize(splashLabel.getPreferredSize());
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the splash screen and frees the memory taken by the image.
     * 
     * Call this function when the loading is complete.
     */
    public void close() {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new SplashScreen().createSplashScreen(new URL(
                            "http://art.gnome.org/download/themes/splash_screens/1334/Splash-GnomeDarkSplashScreen.png"));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add `drawComponents(getGraphics());`, but now it works! Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

1) `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);`

should be

```
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), SplashScreen.this);
```

[code from](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SplashScreenextendsJWindow.htm)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class SplashScreen extends JWindow {
  private JProgressBar bar;
  private JLabel label;

  public SplashScreen(final BufferedImage img) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(),
            SplashScreen.this);
      }
    };
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));

    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    content.add(label = new JLabel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(bar = new JProgressBar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }

  public void setMessage(String msg) {
    label.setText(msg);
    pack();
  }

  public void setProgress(int prog) {
    bar.setValue(prog);
  }

  public void setIndeterminateProgress(boolean value){
    bar.setIndeterminate(value);
  }
}
```

2) I'd suggest to use `JWindow` or `undecorated JDialog` rather than [JFrame (from tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

Comment: Yup that works too. And good advice on using JWindow or JDialog. Although there is one thing I like with the JFrame: you get an icon in the taskbar.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet aaaach I was "uncomfortable" surprised that basic tutorial advice usage of JFrame, +1

Answer (score 0):

Override the `paint` method instead of creating your own `Graphics`.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Every time you call `repaint`, it is in turn calling this method. By default, this method would fill the `JFrame` with the background color (gray).

Comment: @m4tx: You should not draw directly on a JFrame. Guillaume's got a better answer, 1+ to him, though better still may be to use the [SplashScreen class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) that comes with Java.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels He can't use the `SplashScreen` class because he's packaging two apps with one jar and he only wants the splash screen to show for one of them.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I think that that could be fixed by leaving the splash screen line out of the manifest, and instead specifying if he will use a splashscreen on the command line when he runs his jar file.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels yeah, I know that I can do this that way... But which normal (read: non-geek) user will know that he has to run that application by command-line? (Especially on Windows) I don't want to create startup scripts. And my own class doesn't limits me.

Comment: @m4tx: Consider 1) using separate jar files, or 2) use an installation program that creates the short-cuts for you that call the jar files correctly.